# ExportMap in OpenLayers not finding canvas property in layers

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to follow this example to export map to canvas:

http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/examples/exportMapCanvas.html

But, it is failing at this line ([ExportMap.js](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/camptocamp/canvas/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Control/ExportMap.js)):
`this.canvasContext.drawImage(layerCanvas, 0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);`

None of the layers seem to have a canvas property (layer.canvas).  Does anyone know how to put the canvas property on the layers?

**Update #1**
I noticed that the canvas property is always undefined:

```
if (layer.canvas !== null)
        {
            this.drawLayer(layer.canvas);    
        }
```

Also the layer.useCanvas is also undefined even though the layer has the value set to:

useCanvas: OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.ONECANVASPERLAYER

CODE:

```
// Setup tiled base layer
            baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "sf:layer01",
                "http://server01:8080/geoserver/sf/wms",
                {
                    "LAYERS": 'sf:layer01',
                    "STYLES": '',
                    TRANSPARENT: 'true',
                    format: 'image/png'
                },
                {
                    visibility: true,
                    buffer: 0,
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: true,
                    yx: { 'EPSG:4326': false },
                    useCanvas: OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.ONECANVASPERLAYER,
                    renderers: ["Canvas"]
                }
            );
```

Comment: which browser / version are you using?

Comment: I tried IE 9, Chrome Version 27.0.1500.0 and FireFox 37.0.2.  Also I noticed the canvas property is always undefined:

Comment: I tried IE 9, Chrome Version 27.0.1500.0 and FireFox 37.0.2.  Also I noticed the useCanvas property is always undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I found out why its not working: ExportMap was never officially released in OpenLayers after camptocamp made the ExportMap changes.